# Rename launchers

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

If you have an application running, you can right click on the item in the unity starter, select "Lock to Launcher", and the program will stay there even if it is closed.

The problem is that the new launcher now has the title the window had when it was locked. This is often not only the name of the program, but also includes additional information, like `app.js - My Project - Visual Studio Code`. It will stay even after unlocking the app.

Is it possible to rename the launcher without taking the hassle of creating a `.desktop` file? Where does unity saves the information of locked launchers?

Comment: The only 'app' icons that can be locked to the unity launcher are representative of .desktop files. The list of them per user is stored  in dconf, viewed with dconf-editor > com > canonical > unity > launcher > favorites or retrieved from cli with `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @doug mentioned in his comment, all launchers can be found in dconf:
<kbd>dconf-editor</kbd> <kbd>com</kbd> <kbd>canonical</kbd> <kbd>unity</kbd> <kbd>launcher</kbd> <kbd>favorites</kbd> or retrieve from cli with:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

In my case, it contained the entry `application://code.desktop`, and I found the `code.desktop` file via `find` in `~/.local/share/applications` using:

```
sudo find / -name "code.desktop"
```

(this file was generated by unity when I locked the app).

After editing the `Name` property in the `.desktop` file I restarted unity via `unity --replace` and the launcher now displays the appropriate name.